# How to hide controls In Ext.net with javascript or in direct events

Tags: c#, ext.net

The problem is simple, I have ids of the contols and i want to show/ hide them on some event.

Actually the problem is i have a direct event on dropdown change i have to hide some controls based on some cases

the code for the direct event is 
     foreach (Control oControl in ProductConfiguration.Controls)
        {
            string strName = oControl.GetType().Name;
            oControl.Visible = false;
             DataRow[] drIRows = dtInfo.Select("ControlId='" + oControl.ID + "' AND   ProductGroupId='" + CboProductGroup.Value + "'");

```
        if (drIRows.Length > 0)
            oControl.Visible = true;
    }
```

but the visible property doesnt works with direct events, so my idea was to use javascript instead, can anyone help.

Comment: have you tried `oControl.Hide();` / `oControl.Show();`?

Comment: if you are saying about the code behind then there is no method hide or show..

Comment: at least in ext.net 2.2 there is... what version you use?

Comment: They are in Ext.NET v1 as well. Probably, it needs to cast a Control to an Ext.NET Control.

Answer (score 1):

After rendering to the page, visibility cannot be modified since the "visible" property refers to whether or not the client even receives the object to be able to place it on the screen.

I suggest two things if you would like to dynamically change this.

1. use Hidden="true" rather than Visible = "false" on the page
2. change your code behind to affect the Hidden property:  oControl.Hidden=false;

If you use Hidden property, the client still receives the control to render (it simply doesn't display if set to true), and it can then be quite easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Hidden property instead.

The difference is explained [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?13114-CLOSED-DirectMethod-call-setting-control-visibility-doesn-t-work&p=54033&viewfull=1#post54033).

Also you can use the Show/Hide methods.